# How to execute bash expression in Docker ENTRYPOINT?

Tags: bash, docker, configuration-files, docker-entrypoint

There's a Docker file for SpringBoot application with this entry point:

```
# some lines omitted

ENTRYPOINT java -jar app.jar --spring.config.additional-location=$(ls /config/*.properties | tr '\n' ',')
```

On container start a host directory is mounted to `/config/` directory:

```
docker run  -p 9999:8080  -v C:/path/to/configuration/:/config   my_image_name
```

And it works as expected, capturing all `*.properties` from the host directory and applying them to the app.

For readability I would like to use the format with array of strings in ENTRYPOINT like this:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "app.jar", "--spring.config.additional-location=$(ls /config/*.properties | tr '\n' ',')"]
```

Unfortunately, the expression inside `$(...)` is not evaluated at the container start and the application throws an exception that clearly shows the problem:

```
ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
             java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load config data from '')'
```

How do I express the ENTRYPOINT arguments so the bash expression in `$()` could be evaluated as in the first case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use bash in entrypoint you need to run `bash`, and not `java`:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "-c", "java -jar app.jar --spring.config.additional-location=$(ls /config/*.properties | tr '\n' ',')"]
```

The first element of an entrypoint is a binary or a script (i.e. *what*) to be executed. The rest (including `CMD`) goes as arguments to it. `bash -c "some string"` runs a sequence of commands passed in a string and it possible to use `bash` expressions in it.

Comment: Note that the non-JSON-array form works by wrapping its string in `/bin/sh -c`, so the only actual difference between this answer and the original question is explicitly selecting bash as the shell.

Comment: Nicely put, @DavidMaze . Do you mind if I add this to the answer?